# c# and functional purity

Tags: c#, class, object

I've been having to use c# lately, which I don't have much experience in. a conundrum I keep finding myself in is, when building a class, having state be dependent on the state initialized before it

```
  class foo{
    public bar_ {get;}
    public dum_ {get;}

    public foo (){
      bar_ = BuildBar();
      dum_ = BuildDum(bar_);
    }
 }
```

its a bit redundant for BuildDum to carry a parameter if it's just going to use something already accessable from a member. on the other hand I like explicitly pointing out dependencies a function relies on

I guess I am asking: what is the best way to handle the situation?

Comment: Mark `BuildBar` and `BuildDum` as `private`.. that should give a real big hint that they only work on data available within the class.  Then add some xml documentation to each function...  on the line before the function definition press `'`(apostrophe) 3 times.

Comment: On a side-note: underscores in a public interface are seriously frowned upon.

Comment: @Underscores is only a small part of the problem: class names should be capitalized, and so should be property names.

Answer (score 1):

Both ways are fine. The current version of `BuildDum` could be made `static`, in which case it's perfectly fine for the method to not access any member variables, because it cannot do it anyway:

```
private static Dum BuildDum(Bar b) {
    ...
}
```

If you make `BuildDum` that accesses `bar_` directly, you should also make it access `_dum`, i.e. it should be a non-static `void`:

```
private void BuildDum() {
    ...
    _dum = ...
}
```

Comment: ive never been comfortable with static functions within a non-static object but this makes perfect sense. well done sir